# some time i get unspecified error in js

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Sometimes we get "Unspecified error" in IE (javascript error), when using MaskedEdit.application build in framework 2.0

if i enable the debuggin javascript setting then i found this error otherwise a particular part of the page doesnot display.

If we debug we can see that it happens on below line

```
//only for ie , for firefox see keydown
            if (document.activeElement)
            {
                if (e.id == document.activeElement.id)
                {
                    hasInitialFocus = true;
                }
            }
```

when i tried to search where this code is written then i found this code in ajaxcontroltool.dll file.

and this dll is of third party and i can't change in this dll so what should i do to solve the problem.

i tried this in IE8,but i didn't get the error in IE8 it means the code run smoothly/errorless in IE8.

i get this error in IE9 as occurence ratio of once in 6 times open a page.

it became my headache if any one know please help me out of this.

It looks like a browser issue or dll issue.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Thanks and regards

shoaib

Answer (score 0):

> and this dll is of third party and i can't change in this dll so what should i do to solve the problem

Actually you can, as the AjaxControlToolkit is an open source project. You can download project source code from the CodePlex: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/ and customize it for your needs